# how to use .Net localization framework when embedding a winforms control in internet explorer

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, com, activex, localization

I have a standalone winforms application localized in 4 languages. For authentication and security reasons, I had to embed the main control in internet explorer (to be able to use an authentication session cookie created earlier when the user sign-in with his browser).

I embedded the control in IE by making my assembly and main control COM visible. It is working fine, except that since my code is running in an IE instance, I cannot set the CurrentUICulture of my threads. As far as I know, this property is the one used by the .Net framework to get localized resources. Given that I cannot set it, what is my best option to use my localized controls whithout coding a localization framework all by myself?

Answer (score 0):

When calling GetString of ResourceManager, you can specify a culture.

Of course, this implies that your own code is reading the resources, not some VS-generated code.